# Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum CSRF token mismatch 419 error

Tags: laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum

I have a Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum CSRF token mismatch 419 error while Laravel is hosted on a server and Nuxt is on localhost on a PC. I have uploaded my Laravel project for getting API on [api.repairtofix.com](https://api.repairtofix.com).

And I am trying to log in from `localhost` in my pc from Nuxt. While clicking on the login button I get the following error.

> {message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception:
> "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}

**Login method**

```
login() {
    this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', { 
        data: this.form 
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(response))
}
```

**.env**

```
APP_URL=http://api.repairtofix.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=api.repairtofix.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=.repairtofix.com,localhost:3000
```

**Kernel.php**

```
'api' => [
    EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

**sanctum.php**

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 
    'api.repairtofix.com,localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
)),
```

**cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login', 'signup', 'getUser'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

// register
Route::get('register', function(Request $request){
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
    ]);

    return $user;
});

// login
Route::post('login', function(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if(!auth()->attempt($credentials)){
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => 'Invalid credentials'
        ]);
    }

    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return response()->json(null, 201);
});

// logout
Route::post('logout', function(Request $request){
    auth()->guard('web')->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    return response()->json(null, 201);
});
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/toast',
],

auth:{
    strategies: {
        'laravelSanctum': {
            provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
            url: 'http://api.repairtofix.com',
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: '/api/login'
                },
                logout: {
                    url: '/api/logout'
                },
                user: {
                    url: '/api/user'
                },
            },
            user: {
                property: false
            }
        },
    },
    redirect: {
        login: "/login",
        logout: "/",
        home: "/"
    }
},
```

Comment: You need to use token-based authentication in this case. Stateful domains and "EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful" are using Laravel's session cookie-based authentication, which is only working when both application share the same top-level domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using SPA authentication with sanctum, both your server and client has to be on the same domain. The client(localhost) and your api is on different domain.

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication)

`In order to authenticate, your SPA and API must share the same top-level domain. However, they may be placed on different subdomains.`

Comment: This enlightened me, thanks. I have my backend and frontend on different domains and nothins was working. I didn't notice that they can be on different subdomains but under the same top-level domain. I guess I will have to use token-based authentication now (JWT).

Comment: UPDATE: I completely forgot that I don't even need to implement JWT because that  would be much complicated unnecessary. Instead I added a CNAME to my domain DNS settings so now both of them live under the same domain like this: 
laravel backend -> api.mydomain.com

nextjs frontend -> mydomain.com

and it works!

Comment: Yeah, that is a common approach.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Axios credentials were not set to true in nuxt.config file, also the text is case sensitive

```
  axios: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials: true,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is maybe a little bit late but others in future.
1-check the api/config/sanctum in laravel and make the ports correct on localhost:xxxx and 127.0.0.1:xxxx
2-on .env file make coorection for SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:xxxx

Answer (score 0):

Add the below statement to your .env file and clear the cache.

```
AIRLOCK_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing a CSRF token mismatch error, particularly a 419 error, in a Nuxt-Laravel-Sanctum setup can be challenging but is a common issue related to web application security. This error occurs when the CSRF token used in a request does not match the one expected by the Laravel backend, often due to token expiration or misconfiguration.

Generally you have to first call.

```
await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie");
```

Before

```
await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/bah/bah/bal");
```

**Note: the base urls must be consistent do not use "localhost" to get the csrf-cookie then "127.0.0.1" to call your api.**

Stick with one. For me i prefer 127.0.0.1

**For a thorough explanation and a solution to this issue, I recommend watching this detailed [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgBq4IVnfnA). It provides an in-depth look into the matter, enhancing your understanding of the situation.**